# How to send an image to the server in android

Tags: php, android

I am developing an android application that can send a picture to a remote server but am gettting the error.

Error is,

```
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386): Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at com.isummation.imageupload.ImageUpload$ImageUploadTask.onPostExecute(ImageUpload.java:201)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at com.isummation.imageupload.ImageUpload$ImageUploadTask.onPostExecute(ImageUpload.java:1)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 13:25:30.848: E/org.json.JSONException(2386):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is,

```
public class ImageUpload extends Activity {
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
private ImageView imgView;
private Button upload;
private EditText caption;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private ProgressDialog dialog;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imageupload);

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Upload);
    caption = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Caption);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImageUpload.this, "Uploading",
                        "Please wait...", true);
                new ImageUploadTask().execute();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.imageupload_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.ic_menu_gallery:
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    PICK_IMAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String filePath = null;

            try {
                // OI FILE Manager
                String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    filePath = selectedImagePath;
                } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                    filePath = filemanagerstring;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                }

                if (filePath != null) {
                    decodeFile(filePath);
                } else {
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
    }
}

class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/kyaloManager/uploadimage.php");

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            entity.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.JPEG"));
            entity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody(caption.getText()
                    .toString()));
            httpPost.setEntity( entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

            String sResponse = reader.readLine();
            return sResponse;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }

        // (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

            if (sResponse != null) {
                JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                int success = JResponse.getInt("SUCCESS");
                String message = JResponse.getString("MESSAGE");
                if (success == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Photo uploaded successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    caption.setText("");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
        // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}

public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
  }
```

php code is,

```
$target_path1 = "images/uploads/";
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
echo "The first file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
" has been uploaded.";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;
}
```

What's wrong in the above code?

Comment: Well, the error is not in these methods, it's in `ImageUpload.java`, line 201.

Comment: i have updated the code, please got through it and see

Comment: Well, the response you process in `onPostExecute()` does not seem to be a String holding *exclusively* JSON data. Look at `sResponse` in a debugger.

Comment: What do u suggest would be the best way to fix that error

Answer (score 0):

For storing images you can convert them to base64 format by adding the below line :

```
String strData = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT); 
entity.addPart("file", strData);
```

For PHP side you can do the following:

```
$fp = fopen( $output_file, "wb" ); 
fwrite( $fp, base64_decode( $strData) ); 
fclose( $fp );
```

where $strData is the base64 encoded string